# Gatsby: Index page "/" fails to load when using MDX, other path loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am using Gatsby to create a documentation site, using `.mdx` to manage contents. I have configured the `gatsby-node.js` and created the template. Everything path works fine, however, the index page fails to fetch results from the GraphQL query. I have cleared the cache and rebuilt the project severally. I tried a fix on [Github](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10394) which suggested renaming the `index.js` to `main.js`. This worked seamlessly on dev but not in prod.

Here's the `gatsby-node.js` file:

```js
const {createFilePath} = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = ({actions, graphql}) => {
    const {createPage} = actions
    const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/postTemplate.js')

    return(graphql(`
    {
        allMdx {
          nodes {
            frontmatter {
              title
            }
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
    } 
    `)).then(result => {
        if(result.errors) {
            throw result.errors
        }

        const posts = result.data.allMdx.nodes

        posts.forEach(post => {
            createPage({
                path: post.fields.slug,
                component: blogPostTemplate,
                context: {
                    slug: post.fields.slug
                }
            })
        })
    })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({node, actions, getNode}) => {
    const { createNodeField } = actions
    if(node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
        const value = createFilePath({node, getNode})
        createNodeField({
            name: `slug`,
            node,
            value
        })
    }
}
```

Here's the `postTemplate.js` file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {graphql} from 'gatsby'
import {MDXRenderer} from 'gatsby-plugin-mdx'

import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';

export default ({data}) => {
  const {body, tableOfContents, fields} = data.mdx
  return (
    <Layout>
      {tableOfContents}
      <MDXRenderer>
        {body}
      </MDXRenderer>
      {fields}
    </Layout>
    
  )
}

export const query  = graphql`
query PostBySlug($slug: String!) {
  mdx (fields: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
    body
    tableOfContents
    fields {
      slug
    }
  }
}
`
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly are you passing `slug` as a context variable to the template and not an `id`?

Comment: I am using the `slug` to build in-page header navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue. I discovered the index (`/`) page wasn't making use of the `postTemplate.js`. So my workaround was to copy the content of the `postTemplate.js` file into the `index.js` file. I then modified the `graphql` query to fetch just the `/` content. I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator for your `createPage` path. I'm assuming your index's slug name is "index".

```
path: post.fields.slug === 'index' ? '/' : `/${post.fields.slug}`
```